# How to get the current URL for a HTML page

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am scraping a website using Nokogiri. This particular website deals with absolute URLs differently.

If I give it a URL like:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link, :allow_redirections => :all))
```

it will redirect to the HTTPS version, and also redirect to the long version of the URL. For example, a link like

```
http://www.website.com/name
```

turns into

```
http://www.website.com/other-area/name
```

This is fine and doesn't really affect my scraper, however, there are certain edge-cases where, if I can tell my scraper what the current URL is, I can avoid them.

After I pass in the above link to my `page` variable, how can I get the current URL of that page after the redirect happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the `open_uri_redirections` gem because `:allow_redirections` is not necessary in Ruby 2.4+.

Save the result of OpenURI's `open`:

```
require 'open-uri'
r = open('http://www.google.com/gmail')
r.base_uri
# #<URI::HTTPS https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#>
page = Nokogiri::HTML(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Mechanize, then you can do:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get url
puts page.uri # this will be the redirected url
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I was going to do this actually, but I decided to go with the answer above (using `open-uri`) as I didn't want to include mechanize only for that one thing.